# Angular catch errors in a central place or component

Tags: authentication, .net-core, error-handling, angular9

I have an Angular 9 project that works with a .NET Core WEB API.
The site features user authentication that is role based. The API returns two types of errors: 401 and 403 depending on the authorization rules for a controller method.

My goal is to display a message in my layout component when the API returns any of these errors, for example:

- 401: 'Session has expired, please log in.'
- 403: 'You do not have access to this feature.'

Is there any way to catch these errors in Angular and know which one was thrown?

Answer (score 1):

You can use interceptors to catch every http requests. In your case you need to catch response. To do it;

At the module which you provided HttpClientModule
*(app/core).module.ts*

```
import { HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { HttpErrorInterceptor } from '<path of interceptor>';

@NgModule({
imports: [HttpClientModule],
providers: [
     {
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: HttpErrorInterceptor,
      multi: true,
    },
  ]
});
```

*error.interceptor.ts*

```
export class HttpErrorInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor(
      // your injections if you need
  ) {}

  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    return next.handle(req).pipe(
      catchError((err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
        switch (err.status) {
          case 401: {
            this.handle401();
          }
          case 403: {
            this.handle403();
          }
        }
        return throwError(err);
      }),
    );
  }
```

Comment: Thank you, very descriptive, I'll upvote and of it works for me I'll mark it as an answer

Comment: I'm having a problem with the name 'catchError'. The error message is "Cannot find name 'catchError'. Did you mean 'RTCError'?". Am I missing any imports or something?

Comment: You can import it from "rxjs/operators"  @JohannesKarsten